# XAML: Vertical CommandBar (on the left)

Tags: xaml, appbar, commandbar

Can you tell me how to make a vertical commandbar in XAML (C#), similar to the one on the left of the "Weather" app in windows 10?
I've been trying but it seems there is only bottom and top bars
thank you

Comment: https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners/UWP-021-Implementing-a-Simple-Hamburger-Navigation-Menu

Comment: thank you, this is really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Weather app, it is called Splitview, [here's how to use it](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2015/04/implementing-hamburger-button-with.html) , by Jerry Nixon

Comment: Problem solved, solution accepted.
Thank you, you're my hero